# Regular expression to find any word starting with this.Apple

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Regular expression to find any word starting with `this.Apple`

I am trying to clean up my code..and got find all words starting with this. and have Capital letter next.

i.e..

```
this.Apple
this.Apple
```

The aim is to remove the `this.` prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this\.[A-Z]
```

1. `this` matches *this* literally
2. `\.` is an escaped *dot* (to match it literally)
3. `[A-Z]` is a range containing all capital letters in the English alphabet. This character set will match exactly one of them

---

**EDIT**: As it turned out after a little clarification in the comments, what is desired here is to remove the `this.` prefix.

We can do this by matching very similarly to the first regex, but using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the capital letter:

```
this\.(?=[A-Z])
```

The difference is that it will now only check that it follows after `this.`, instead of including it in the match. Now you can replace the matches with an empty string and you are all done.

Comment: Can we have regular expression for this  this.Apple to Apple i.e Just get rid of this. for all words starting with Capital Letter

Comment: remove all this. from code  My code as this.GetXyz()  so I want to make it just GetXyz()    " remove this. from the words  and word starts with CapitalLetter

Comment: just like  we have this.GetStackoverflow()    .I want to change it to GetStackoverflow()  I am using visual studio to find match words and i want to replace this. with empty space.

Comment: kool.I understood it now.Thanks for your quick reply.